# Countable open covering of normal space

Tags: gn.general-topology, separation-axioms

I read the following claim in Z.Frolik's article "A generalization of realcompact spaces" on page 135.

Two subset $M$ and $N$ of a space $X$ are called completely seperated if there exists a real valued continuous function $f$ on $X$ with $f(M)\subset \{0\}$ and $f(N)\subset\{1\}$.

**Claim:** Let $X$ be a normal space. For every countable open covering $\mathfrak{U}$ of $X$, there exists a countable open covering $\mathfrak{B}$ of $X$ such that for every $B$ in $\mathfrak{B}$ there exists an $A$ in $\mathfrak{U}$ such that $B$ and $X-A$ are completely seperated.

I didn't show the proof of the claim.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The existence of $\mathfrak{B}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claim is false it would imply that normal spaces are countably paracompact and hence that normality of $X$ would imply normality of $X\times[0,1]$. The latter is not the case, see [Mary Ellen Rudin, *A normal space $X$ for which $X\times I$ is not normal*, Fundamenta Mathematicae, **73** (1971/72), 179-186](https://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm73/fm73121.pdf).

To show that the property in the claim implies countable paracompactness we use Theorem 5.2.1 in Engelking's *General Topology*. Let $\{U_n:n\in\omega\}$ be an increasing open cover; we need to find open $O_n$ such that $\operatorname{cl}O_n\subseteq U_n$ for all $n$ and $\bigcup_nO_n=X$. Take an open cover $\{V_m:m\in\omega\}$ as in the claim; hence for every $m$ an $n$ such that $\operatorname{cl}V_m\subseteq U_n$. Now define $O_n=\bigcup\{V_m:m\le n$ and $\operatorname{cl}V_m\subseteq U_n\}$; then $\operatorname{cl}O_n\subseteq U_n$ for all $n$ and the $O_n$ form a cover (if $x\in V_m$ and $\operatorname{cl}V_m\subseteq U_n$ then $x\in O_n$).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, Theorem 11 in Frolik's article on 136 is not true .

Comment: That I do not know, all this says is that the proof contains a gap: Rudin's space is not a counterexample to Theorem 11 as it is not almost realcompact. See P. Simon, A note on Rudin's example of Dowker space [https://eudml.org/doc/16467]

Comment: Would you expand on your answer to make it clearer what you state. (As it is, it is hard to parse the logic of your Answer).